# where to store - access token and refresh token in OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I am new to OAuth 2.0 and I wish to know what is the best practice / location to store access token and refresh token in generic e-commerce web site.

Question 1: 
Where should access token and refresh token be stored in web sites? (cookies, web storage or local storage). And where big companies like google, dropbox store the access token and refresh token?

Question 2: 
If refresh token is stored on the client side (taking browser in desktop/laptop), isn't it possible that someone has physical gain on that device able to get the refresh token and device information and use it to generate access token on other place?

Question 3: 
I have see some post that suggest that refresh token should never be stored and known by client side. Then, where should refresh token be stored and how to reauthenticate in this case?

Answer (score -1):

A1: access token has a much shorter time-to-live than refresh token, you may store refresh token in local storage or even other secure storage on server side; for access token, both web storage and local storage are fine; storing access token in cookie does not make much sense

A2: yes, hence refresh token should not be stored on client side;

A3: stored it on server/service side

Answer (score -1):

A1 -- you must store refresh token in **http-cookie** (which is not accessible by js) and **database both** and validate cookie refresh token using database. Store access token in **memory or session storage** but it must expires in a short period of time

ANSWER 1, ANSWERS BOTH QUESTION 1 AND 3

Comment: It makes 0 sense to store an OAuth2 refresh token in a cookie. If your OAuth2 client is in the browser, there's no point in ever sending it to a server and Javascript already has access. If your OAuth2 client is server-side the refresh token should be stored securely on the server and never sent to the client.