# Where to store refresh token safely

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh-token

This [where to store - access token and refresh token in OAuth 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620689/where-to-store-access-token-and-refresh-token-in-oauth-2-0) is the answer I was looking for but I have something that's not clear to me or maybe I'm just overthinking it.

Let's say I have a website X that calls a REST api and stores the refresh token in the browser as an HttpOnly cookie. If a malicious man M gets into some other guys computer that's already logged in X as U, M can go and look for the cookie and steal that refresh token. Then M will be able to retrieve all the tokens he wants for U, he will just need the client Id and client secret of that application, which he can get from any other user of the application, for example he himself M by just looking at the value of the header when a GET new access token call is made. Is that correct ?

Comment: What do you mean by the "website X"? An HTML+JavaScript application? What's your reason for storing a refresh token as a cookie? Who is the consumer of the access/ID token?

Comment: Yes, website X would be an HTML+Javascript app. The documentation always say that refresh tokens should be stored somewhere safe  and cookies would be the safest available place in this case, not vulnerable to XSS or CSRF attacks. The consumer of the token? The token should be used by the website to request something to the rest api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the Authentication Code grant in application running in browser. The [Implicit grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) is designed for such applications:

- To get an access tokens from a refresh token, you need to make a request to the `/token` endpoint which requires authentication (client ID and client secret) and you cannot keep the secret safe in a browser.
- The `/token` endpoint usually doesn't support CORS headers - you cannot access it by JavaScript XHR calls.
- To get a new access token when the original one expires, you can use the [`prompt=none`](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) `/auth` request parameter.

Comment: That is an outdated advice, do not use implicit grant, use Auth Code grant with PKCE if needed https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant-pkce